# get window width on the fly after a click function

Tags: jquery

I need to get the width of the window to keep updating after I have clicked a button

If I drag the browser the the window width stays the same unless I click again.  I need to to constantly update as you drag the brower.  The click neds to be here as there will be multiple clicks that update the widht of a div so will carry calculations

http://jsfiddle.net/ktcle/36bnm/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
function checkWidth() {
    function Click()
    {
        var $window = $(window);
    var windowsize = $window.width();
    $('div#BB  span').html( windowsize)
    }

    window.Click = Click;
 };

checkWidth();
$(window).resize(checkWidth);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to *call* your update function when the resize event triggers.
Currently you only reassign the click function.

```
function checkWidth() { 
   var $window = $(window);
   var windowsize = $window.width();
   $('div#BB  span').html( windowsize)
}

$(document).ready(function() {    
   checkWidth();
   $(window).resize(checkWidth);
});
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/36bnm/1/

The button is obsolete now.

edit:
To trigger this after the click you do this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
   $('button').click(function() {
     checkWidth();
     $(window).resize(checkWidth);
   });
});
```

So the event handler for resize only fires after the button has been pressed.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the `Click()` method here, just use:

```
function checkWidth() {
    var $window = $(window);
    var windowsize = $window.width();
    $('div#BB  span').html(windowsize)
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).resize(checkWidth);
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/36bnm/3/)**

Comment: i need the click as I will be having multiple clicks that that have a calculation - so one click will be windsize-200 etc and need to be clicked on to update a div width

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add the `Click` method to your logic, simply define the function in the global scope and attach it as an event handler on `$(document).ready()`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(window).resize(checkWidth);
});

function checkWidth() {
  var $window = $(window);
  var windowsize = $window.width();
  $('div#BB  span').html(windowsize)
}
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/36bnm/5/)

Comment: i need the click as I will be having multiple clicks that that have a calculation - so one click will be windsize-200 etc